# Can an action call more than one render

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Can I have an action call the render method more than once?

```
def someAction() {
  render f.field()
  render f.field()
}
```

We are trying to render two fields from the fields plugin to an ajax response to update a div. Are there any issues using render this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the correct way, if you want to update more than one element, you can render the fields via json, something like this:

```
render ([fieldOne : f.field(), fieldTwo : f.field()] as JSON)
```

Then in the JavaScript response, you can handle the two fields and update both.
P/D: You must import the grails converters to use "as JSON" statement

```
import grails.converters.JSON
```

Comment: I was able to find one example of multiple renders, but I believe your approach is better.  http://grails.asia/grails-render-examples

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

```
class ExampleController {
  def action1() {
    render text: 'text1'
    render text: 'text2'
    action2()
  }

  def action2() {
    render text: 'text3'
  }
}
```

You can call renders until response is closed.

```
class ExampleController {
  def action1() {
    render text: 'text1'
    return // finishing response
    action2()
  }

  def action2() {
    render text: 'will not be rendered'
  }
}
```

P.S. I have never done this way. It is better and clearer to call render once at the end of the action than several calls in different places.

Comment: I think this is the technically correct answer, though I still cannot find any documentation supporting it. It makes perfect sense to me that the render just dumps the resulting output to the response and hence can be called more than once, but our team chose to go with the JSON approach to better fit the documented approach.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You could, however, have your controller to render in different format using `withFormat`:

```
withFormat {
            html bookList:books
            js { render "alert('hello')" }
            xml { render books as XML }
            json { render books as JSON}
        }
```